# I can't seems to be able to create a thumb up and thumb down path in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, paint

Pls can anyone help me out pls, I want to draw custom thumb up and thumb down in flutter.
Thanks

I've not tried anything yet, hope anyone can help.
Thanks

Comment: It will be little complicated I think, btw how about using icon? Can you include your current snippet ?

Comment: I don't even know how to go about it, though I was able to create heart shape path, but I can't just do the thumb up & down thing

Comment: you can use the bezier curve

Comment: The coordinates are the my problem, I know about bezier, but can anyone help with the path coordinates, I can do the rest